# Variable array with UITextfiles

Tags: ios, swift

I create in the `ViewControler` a variable with an array of `UITextFields` like this:

```
var arrayTextFields = [textField1, textField2, textField3]
```

I want to use it in the `ViewDidLoad` or in a function but I can’t.

What do I have to do?

Comment: show us the error

Comment: @Taco what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have connected the outlets to `UITextView`s You need to define it within the class declaration and not in any of the methods.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField3: UITextField!

    // define and initialize empty array, can be accessed anywhere within the class
    var arrayTextFields: [UITextField] = []  

    override func viewDidLoad(animated: Bool) {
        // set the array in viewDidLoad
        arrayTextFields = [textField1, textField2, textField3]  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am new in Xcode! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you connect it to your source file by dragging it from the storyboard while holding "control". then if you follow the code mentioned above, you should have access to do whatever you want.